# jQuery - select children which has specific styles

Tags: jquery

I do not know how to select the first span in the following example.

```
<div class="sp">
  <span style="visibility:hidden">abc</span>
  <span>xyz</span>
</div>
```

I have tried using this one, did not work.

```
$('div.sp span[visibility=hidden]') // not work
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.sp span[style="visibility:hidden"]')
```

See [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

In your selector you did not mention the attribute name(`style`) and also the quotes are missing wrapping the complete selector. Try this

```
$("div.sp span[style='visibility:hidden']");
```

If you are looking to find a hidden span then I would suggest you to use this because attribute selector will try to match `visibility:hidden` as it is. If there is any space between this value then it will fail. `:hidden` selector looks for element which are not `visible` or `display` is `none`.

```
$("div.sp span:hidden")
```

Comment: [:hidden Selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) will not select `visibility:hidden`, Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Get **first span**:

```
$('div.sp span:first');
```

If you want get the **first span with visibility:hidden**, is other thing:

```
$('.sp span[style="visibility:hidden"]:first');
```