# jquery select parent that has children with certain attributes

Tags: jquery, styles, selector, children

I've read this SO question :

[jQuery - select children which has specific styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349858/jquery-select-children-which-has-specific-styles)

but my problem is a bit different.

I want to select PARENTS that their 1st-level children (not all descendants) have some certain styles. Something like this :

```
<ul id="BIG">
    <li>Home

        <ul id="SMALL">
            <li> 123 </li>
            <li name="foo"> 123 </li>
            <li> 123 </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>Articles</li>
    <li>Petitions</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to catch the UL with id="SMALL". But my selector catch all 2 UL tags :

```
$('ul:has(li[name="foo"])')
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Your question is not about style attribute, I think title should be changed

Comment: thanks, I've just changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector `>`, like this:

```
$('ul > li[name="foo"]').parent()
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/ccar2/1/)

Comment: I didn't think .parent() can return more than 1 element. Many thanks

Comment: Sure it can. parent() returns a collection of parents - one parent for each element selected by the selector $(...). http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('li[name="foo"]').parent();
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ht7Em/).

Please note, selecting DOM elements based on their attributes is slow. Try to limit the scope of the search if you can. For example:

```
$('#BIG').find('li[name="foo"]').parent();
```